# JFreeChart DynamicTimeSeriesCollection with a period of n milliseconds

Tags: java, jfreechart, milliseconds

I'm trying to define an applet with a chart that have to be updated every n milliseconds.
For example every 500 milliseconds. This is a part of the code:

```
dataSet = new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, 200, new Millisecond());
dataSet.setTimeBase(new Millisecond());
```

When I launch the application it returns me a NullPointerException raised by the second line. If I replace Milliseconds with Seconds it works.

The question is: how can I set a period of n milliseconds without having exceptions?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `pointsInTime` is not being initialized for `Millisecond`, but you can do so in a subclass constructor:

```
private static class MilliDTSC extends DynamicTimeSeriesCollection {

    public MilliDTSC(int nSeries, int nMoments, RegularTimePeriod timeSample) {
        super(nSeries, nMoments, timeSample);
        if (timeSample instanceof Millisecond) {
            this.pointsInTime = new Millisecond[nMoments];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, is that a JFreeCharts bug, then?

Comment: Arguably, yes; the comment in the source suggests more of a _todo_.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow morning at the office.
How can I set a 500 milliseconds period? Does it depend on the frequency with which I add new data?

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot !!! Now I only have the doubts about the period of 500 ms.

Comment: @trashgod. You are perfectly right. As I said in the question if I use seconds insted milliseconds it works. Anyway the solution proposed in this answer works.

Comment: You can `advanceTime()` as needed; see also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852/using-jfreechart-to-display-recent-changes-in-a-time-series/5048863#5048863).

Comment: Sorry, it will be the last question ;) I looked the example and i used it as guide when I started building my application. It seems that the period 'x' value of a sample in a series depends on the time in which I add it. It's correct? If a will ad A sample at the time 0.1 sec and another one at the time 0.3 sec then 0.1 and 0.3 will be the 'x' values of the two samples? Thanks

Comment: Ah, I think you can use `addValue()` to get the effect you want.

Comment: Yes! That's what i tried to explain in the previous comment ;) Thanks

Comment: Mmm...unfortunately it doesn't work...if I add the data every 500 milliseconds the gap between two samples in the chat remains 1 ms. How can I manage it?
I need at least to set the period on the x values to a multiple of 1 ms, for example 500ms.

Comment: I did that:
    dataset = new MilliDTSC(new Millisecond());
    dataset.setBaseTime(new Millisecond);

I add samples every 500 ms but the times reported on the X axis are not consistent. For example I see 10:00:00.000 and the next one is 10:00:00:025. I have 25 samples in this space, one for each millisecond.
What I expected is to have 10:00:00:000 and 10:00:12:500.

Comment: I'm tryng to extend the class Millisecond and overriding the methods next and previous in such a way that they return a t + 500ms value and a t-500ms value. But it doesn't work...I'm missing something

Comment: @trashgod Just for completeness this is what I do when I add a sample: `dataSet.advanceTime()` and `dataset.appendData(newData)`.

Comment: This is a little hard to follow in comments. You might want to put put together an [ssce](http://sscce.org/) and pose a new question.

Comment: @trashgod I did it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856979/jfreechart-dynamictimeseries-with-period-of-n-milliseconds)