# JFreeChart Timeseries RegularTimePeriod

Tags: java, jfreechart, time-series

I can use a [`TimeSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeries.html) to plot 1 minute data using `JFreeChart`. I'm wondering if there's an easy to plot other time intervals like 5 min or 15 min, etc? It seems like there are only `Minute`, `Hour`, `Day`, etc. for [`RegularTimePeriod`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/RegularTimePeriod.html) implementation.

Comment: If this is a duplicate account, you can request a [merge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste/73801#73801) of your other account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could introduce a new [`org.jfree.data.time.RegularTimePeriod`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/RegularTimePeriod.html), such as `PentaMinute` or `QuarterHour`, but I'm skeptical of the usefulness. Alternatively, you might examine the approach adopted for a period of *n* `Millisecond`, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850326/jfreechart-dynamictimeseriescollection-with-a-period-of-n-milliseconds) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856979/jfreechart-dynamictimeseries-with-period-of-n-milliseconds).