# Dynamic JFreeChart with custom x-axis values

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852/using-jfreechart-to-display-recent-changes-in-a-time-series) example of jfreechart to plot a moving graph using DynamicTimeSeriesCollection class. I need the same with custom X-Axis values. The values would be in the range of milliseconds, so I can't use Second class' constructor.

Please explain in a bit detail, I have just started with JFreeChart today

Comment: Have you tried `org.jfree.data.time.Millisecond`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Millisecond`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/Millisecond.html) in `DynamicTimeSeriesCollection`

Comment: found the solution, exact solution is here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850326/jfreechart-dynamictimeseriescollection-with-a-period-of-n-milliseconds