# DynamicTimeSeriesCollection with custom time steps

Tags: java, user-interface, jfreechart

I'm trying to use DynamicTimeSeriesCollection but with custom time ticks, but haven't found any documentation so far.

Currently, I'm using Hour as the time base, so my time steps are 0, 1, 24, then repeat. But I only want 5 hours a day.
I want to custom the domain so that it will display only 5 hours betwen 7am and 11am: 7am, 8am, 9am, 10am, 11am then repeat, and not the entire 24 hours.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JFreeChart DynamicTimeSeriesCollection with a period of n milliseconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850326/jfreechart-dynamictimeseriescollection-with-a-period-of-n-milliseconds)

Comment: No. This is NOT a duplicate. I've looked at that question before. What I'm trying to achieve is different. I want to be able to custom the domain my time series.

Comment: Have you tried a [`SegmentedTimeline`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20SegmentedTimeline)?

Comment: Yeah I found that, but it doesn't advance past 5 hours of the first day, so I'm not exactly sure if I'm using it correctly and there's no documentation around that. Can you give some pointers as to where to find some examples?